# Printing tuples in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not getting how to proceed with this problem in lists,can any one help me out?
Thanks in advance.

input is :

```
l = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

output is:

```
[(1,3,5),(2,4,6)]
```

Comment: Please be specific in the requirements

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: it's an interview question, nothing much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oneliner:

```
list(zip(*l))
# [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Comment: can you explain me more elobratley