# The fastest way to create np.arrays for each item from list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance, numpy

There is a list of tuples `l = [(x,y,z), (x,y,z), (x,y,z)]`
The idea is to find the fastest way to create different np.arrays for each x-s, y-s, z-s. Need help with finding the fastest solution to do it. To make speed comparison I use code attached below

```
import time

def myfast():
   code

n = 1000000
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(n): myfast()
t1 = time.time()

total_n = t1-t0

1.  np.array([i[0] for i in l])
    np.array([i[1] for i in l])
    np.array([i[2] for i in l])
```

> output: 0.9980638027191162

```
2.  array_x = np.zeros((len(l), 1), dtype="float")
    array_y  = np.zeros((len(l), 1), dtype="float")
    array_z  = np.zeros((len(l), 1), dtype="float")

    for i, zxc in enumerate(l):
        array_x[i] = zxc[0]
        array_y[i] = zxc[1]
        array_z[i] = zxc[2]
```

> output 5.5509934425354

```
3. [np.array(x) for x in zip(*l)]
```

> output 2.5070037841796875

```
5. array_x, array_y, array_z = np.array(list(zip(*l)))
```

> output 2.725318431854248

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing tuples in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54662656/printing-tuples-in-a-list)

Comment: @Chris This is a speed comparison for finding the fastest solution. Not just any solution that can be found on stackoverflow. P.S the solution from that post works slower than my 1st solution :) Have a nice day

Comment: Yes, but for longer lists if you want to avoid writing as many list comprehensions as items in the tuples, `zip` is what you want. Btw note that the solution from rusu is not giving the result you want...

Comment: @yatu Thanks a lot for the explanation, I've got your point . But in my case there are not so much items to create lots of list comprehension.

Comment: array_x, array_y, array_z = np.array(l) (my initial idea) will not solve the problem in the right way

Comment: @rusu_ro1 Thanks, I removed it

Comment: If you are using (or have access to) IPython, you want to use the `%timeit` magic instead of your hand-made solution for the timing. Also, this is the kind stuff that does depend on the size of the input. Would you have some insights on that?

Comment: first method is just not practical, (you have to write to much code if your len(l) = 1023131 for example

Comment: I added an answer comparing the different suggestions. I used the standard `timeit` module. @IvanShelonik

Comment: @Ralf Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some really good option in here, so I summarized them and compared speed:

```
import numpy as np

def f1(input_data):
    array_x = np.array([elem[0] for elem in input_data])
    array_y = np.array([elem[1] for elem in input_data])
    array_z = np.array([elem[2] for elem in input_data])

    return array_x, array_y, array_z

def f2(input_data):
    array_x = np.zeros((len(input_data), ), dtype="float")
    array_y = np.zeros((len(input_data), ), dtype="float")
    array_z = np.zeros((len(input_data), ), dtype="float")

    for i, elem in enumerate(input_data):
        array_x[i] = elem[0]
        array_y[i] = elem[1]
        array_z[i] = elem[2]

    return array_x, array_y, array_z

def f3(input_data):
    return [np.array(elem) for elem in zip(*input_data)]

def f4(input_data):
    return np.array(list(zip(*input_data)))

def f5(input_data):
    return np.array(input_data).transpose()

def f6(input_data):
    array_all = np.array(input_data)
    array_x = array_all[:, 0]
    array_y = array_all[:, 1]
    array_z = array_all[:, 2]

    return array_x, array_y, array_z
```

First I asserted that all of them return the same data (using `np.array_equal()`):

```
data = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
for array_list in zip(f1(data), f2(data), f3(data), f4(data), f5(data), f6(data)):
    # print()
    # for i, arr in enumerate(array_list):
    #     print('array from function', i+1)
    #     print(arr)
    for i, arr in enumerate(array_list[:-1]):
        assert np.array_equal(arr, array_list[i+1])
```

And the time comparisson:

```
import timeit
for f in [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6]:
    t = timeit.timeit('f(data)', 'from __main__ import data, f', number=100000)
    print('{:5s} {:10.4f} seconds'.format(f.__name__, t))
```

gives these results:

```
data = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]    # 3 tuples
timeit number=100000
f1        0.3184 seconds
f2        0.4013 seconds
f3        0.2826 seconds
f4        0.2091 seconds
f5        0.1732 seconds
f6        0.2159 seconds

data = [(1, 2, 3) for _ in range(10**6)]    # 1 millon tuples
timeit number=10
f1        2.2168 seconds
f2        2.8657 seconds
f3        2.0150 seconds
f4        1.9790 seconds
f5        2.6380 seconds
f6        2.6586 seconds
```

making `f5()` the fastest option for short input and `f4()` the fastest option for big input.

---

If the number of elements in each tuple will be more than 3, then only 3 functions apply to that case (the others are hardcoded for 3 elements in each tuple):

```
data = [tuple(range(10**4)) for _ in range(10**3)]
timeit number=10
f3       11.8396 seconds
f4       13.4672 seconds
f5        4.6251 seconds
```

making `f5()` again the fastest option for these criteria.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you will get noticeably different results for different sizes of your input.

Comment: @Ralf, great job, thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: List of 1 million tuples (timeit repeat 10x):
f1        2.5675 seconds
f2        2.8918 seconds
f3        2.2974 seconds
**f4        2.2843 seconds**
f5        2.6894 seconds
f6        2.6799 seconds

Comment: @HåkonT. I added it to my answer; you are right, `f4` is faster for larger input

Comment: Also, this is not entirely fair, as the results are slightly different. In some cases you get a `np.ndarray` and in some others you get a `list` or a `tuple`. It is not clear whether this is relevant for OP, but it is certainly noteworthy, as this will add up to the final timings.

Comment: For large inputs, using a list comprehension for the *coordinate* dimension may be faster than the `zip` or `transpose` approach. This might be related to memory paging.

Answer (score 2):

you could try:

```
import numpy
array_x, array_y, array_z = numpy.array(list(zip(*l)))
```

or just:

```
numpy.array(list(zip(*l)))
```

and more elegant way:

```
numpy.array(l).transpose()
```

Comment: I added an answer comparing the different suggestions, using the standard `timeit` module. Your proposal using `.transpose()` is the fastest for this small input data.

Comment: good job, I think also for big data is the fastest (blind trust for ppl job on numpy)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something, but why not just pass list of tuples directly to `np.array`? Say if:

```
n = 100
l = [(0, 1, 2) for _ in range(n)]

arr = np.array(l)
x = arr[:, 0]
y = arr[:, 1]
z = arr[:, 2]
```

Btw, I prefer to use the following to time code:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

t0 = timer()
do_heavy_calculation()
print("Time taken [sec]:", timer() - t0)
```

Comment: I added an answer comparing the different suggestions, using the the standard `timeit` module. I agree with you, that `timeit` should be preferred for measuring time for code speed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe most (but not all) of the ingredients of this answer are actually present in the other answers, but on all the answers so far I have not seen a apple-to-apple comparison, in the sense that some approaches were not returning a list of `np.ndarray` objects, but rather a (convenient in my opinion) single `np.ndarray()`.

It is not clear whether this is acceptable to you, so I am adding proper code for this.
Besides that the performances may be different because is some cases you are adding an extra step, while for some others you may not need to create large objects (that could reside in different memory pages).

In the end, for smaller inputs (3 x 10), the list of `np.ndarray()`s is just some additional burden that adds up significantly to the timing.
For larger inputs (3 x 1000) and above the extra computation is not significant any longer, but an approach involving comprehensions and avoiding the creation of a large `numpy` array can becomes as fast as (or even *faster* than) the fastest methods for smaller inputs.

Also, all the code I present work for arbitrary sizes of the tuples/list (as long as the inner tuples all have the same size, of course).

*(EDIT: added a comment on the final results)*

---

The tested methods are:

```
import numpy as np


def to_arrays_zip(items):
    return np.array(list(zip(*items)))


def to_arrays_transpose(items):
    return np.array(items).transpose()


def to_arrays_zip_split(items):
    return [arr for arr in np.array(list(zip(*items)))]


def to_arrays_transpose_split(items):
    return [arr for arr in np.array(items).transpose()]


def to_arrays_comprehension(items):
    return [np.array([items[i][j] for i in range(len(items))]) for j in range(len(items[0]))]


def to_arrays_comprehension2(items):
    return [np.array([item[j] for item in items]) for j in range(len(items[0]))]
```

(This is a convenient function to check that the results are the same.)

```
def test_equal(items1, items2):
    return all(np.all(x == y) for x, y in zip(items1, items2))
```

---

For small inputs:

```
N = 3
M = 10
ll = [tuple(range(N)) for _ in range(M)]

print(to_arrays_comprehension2(ll))

print('Returning `np.ndarray()`')
%timeit to_arrays_zip(ll)
# 2.82 µs ± 28 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit to_arrays_transpose(ll)
# 3.18 µs ± 30 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

print('Returning a list')
%timeit to_arrays_zip_split(ll)
# 3.71 µs ± 47 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit to_arrays_transpose_split(ll)
# 3.97 µs ± 42.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit to_arrays_comprehension(ll)
# 5.91 µs ± 96.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit to_arrays_comprehension2(ll)
# 5.14 µs ± 109 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Where the podium is:

1. `to_arrays_zip_split()` (the non-`_split` if you are OK with a single array)
2. `to_arrays_zip_transpose_split()` (the non-`_split` if you are OK with a single array)
3. `to_arrays_comprehension2()`

---

For somewhat larger inputs:

```
N = 3
M = 1000
ll = [tuple(range(N)) for _ in range(M)]

print('Returning `np.ndarray()`')
%timeit to_arrays_zip(ll)
# 146 µs ± 2.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit to_arrays_transpose(ll)
# 222 µs ± 2.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

print('Returning a list')
%timeit to_arrays_zip_split(ll)
# 147 µs ± 1.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit to_arrays_transpose_split(ll)
# 221 µs ± 2.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit to_arrays_comprehension(ll)
# 261 µs ± 2.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit to_arrays_comprehension2(ll)
# 212 µs ± 1.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The podium becomes:

1. `to_arrays_zip_split()` (whether you use the `_split` or non-`_split` variants, does not make much difference)
2. `to_arrays_comprehension2()`
3. `to_arrays_zip_transpose_split()` (whether you use the `_split` or non-`_split` variants, does not make much difference)

---

For even larger inputs:

```
N = 3
M = 1000000
ll = [tuple(range(N)) for _ in range(M)]

print('Returning `np.ndarray()`')
%timeit to_arrays_zip(ll)
# 215 ms ± 4.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit to_arrays_transpose(ll)
# 220 ms ± 4.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

print('Returning a list')
%timeit to_arrays_zip_split(ll)
# 218 ms ± 6.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit to_arrays_transpose_split(ll)
# 222 ms ± 3.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit to_arrays_comprehension(ll)
# 248 ms ± 3.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit to_arrays_comprehension2(ll)
# 186 ms ± 481 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The podium becomes:

1. `to_arrays_comprehension2()`
2. `to_arrays_zip_split()` (whether you use the `_split` or non-`_split` variants, does not make much difference)
3. `to_arrays_zip_transpose_split()` (whether you use the `_split` or non-`_split` variants, does not make much difference)

and the the `_zip` and `_transpose` variants are pretty close to each other.

(I also tried to speed things up with Numba that didn't go well)